# Swap images and disabling buttons using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I'm using icons to create 6 separate buttons. Each button has an active and inactive state (two different images). How can I swap images when a button is active and disable any other button that was made active beforehand?

Here's a snippet of the JQuery code I'm using to swap the images

```
$(".img-swap").on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).attr("class") == "img-swap") {
      this.src = this.src.replace("_btn","_active");
    } else {
      this.src = this.src.replace("_active","_btn");
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

And here is a snippet of how my buttons are laid out in HTML/erb:

```
<button class="event-btn" disabled>
    <%= link_to image_tag("example_btn.png", class: "img-swap"), "#"  %>
</button>
```

Thank you very much in advance! I'm still learning and this will help tremendously!

Comment: First, you  probably don't want a link within a button. Secondly, it is better to use CSS rules to change the appearance depending on element state.